# Bootstrap стили только для DatePicker

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, frontend, datepicker

Использую DatePicker от bootstrap, но вся стилизация bootstrap мне не нужна, нарушает собственную. Как я могу выделить только нужные мне стили? Не могу понять, какие селекторы "выдернуть" из основного bootstrap.css файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно оставить только стили:

```css
.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 270px;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu tbody {
  height: 180px;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu.datepicker-mode-1 tbody button,
.datepicker.dropdown-menu.datepicker-mode-2 tbody button {
  height: 65px;
}

.timepicker.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.bs-header .container,
.select.dropdown-menu.select-multiple li {
  position: relative;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu button,
.timepicker.dropdown-menu button {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu tbody button,
.timepicker.dropdown-menu tbody button {
  padding: 6px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1030;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  visibility: visible;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.tooltip.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  opacity: .9;
}

.tooltip.top {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.tooltip.right {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.tooltip.bottom {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.tooltip.left {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

.tooltip.top-left .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

.tooltip.top-right .tooltip-arrow {
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-right-color: #000;
}

.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #000;
}

.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.tooltip.bottom-left .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.tooltip.bottom-right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но пропали стрелки управления месяцами и пр.
Из оригинального файла вытянул .glyphicon селекторы, но не решило вопрос

Comment: Тогда воспользуйтесь https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/ и вытащите все необходимые стили